# Not able to use HBaseTestingUtility with CDH 5.7

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to use `HBaseTestingUtility` with CDH 5.7 as mentioned in the below blog and github

- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-test-hbase-applications-using-popular-tools/
- https://github.com/sitaula/HBaseTest

I have modified my `pom.xml` for CDH 5.7 like below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HBaseTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.7.1</hadoop.version>
        <hbase.version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</hbase.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>${hbase.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>${hbase.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But on trying to do `mvn clean install` it is failing with the below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Test: Could not resolve dependencies for project HBaseTest:Test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0, org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:tests:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0: Failure to find org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct set of dependencies that is working

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HBaseTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.7.0</hadoop.version>
        <hbase.version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</hbase.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-testing-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```